# Error in extract value from href with JQuery in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, href

My blade is loading like this

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="table-layout: fixed;">
@foreach ($product as $product)
 <tr>
     <td><h6><img src="{{asset('assets/products/'.$product->img)}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 100px"></h6></td>
     <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>    
     <td style="word-wrap:break-word; width: 45%;">{{$product->description}}</td>
     <td>${{$product->product_price}}</td> 
     <td colspan="3">
           <a href="{{url('admin/set/status/product?id='.$product['product_id'])}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?')" class="{{$product['status']==1 ? 'btn btn-danger btn-lnk' : 'btn btn-success btn-lnk'}}">{{$product['status']==0 ? 'Enable ':'Disable'}}</a>                        
           <a href="{{url('/admin/product/edit?id='.$product['product_id'])}}" class="btn btn-info btn-lnk">Edit</a>

            //modal load from this link
           <a href="#{{$product['product_id']}}" class="btn btn-success btn-lnk" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="code">+Add File</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach                   
 </table>
```

My model is like this

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
               <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                       <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Upload Your File for {{$product['product_name']}}</h4>
                   </div>
                   <!-- START OF MODAL BODY-->                                  
                   <div class="modal-body" style="padding-left: 10%">
                       <p>Please choose a file to upload. EXE, ISO, RAR, ZIP.</p>
                       <form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{url('admin/addproductexe')}}" id="frm_01" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

                          //load value from <a href>
                           <input type="text" name="Id" id="Id" value=""/>


                           <label for="file">File input</label>
                           <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="" name="fileField" />
                           <p></p>                                    
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lnk">Upload</button>
                       </form>
                   </div>                                        
                   <!-- END OF APPLICATION FORM MODAL BODY -->
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lnk" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                   </div>
               </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
           </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
       </div>
```

And my JS is this

```
<script>
var clearBn = $("#code");
clearBn.on("click", function(){
var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var hashPosition = link.indexOf('#'); //Get the position of '#'
    var number = link.substring(hashPosition + 1); //Split the string and get the number.
    $(".modal-body #Id").val( number );
});
</script>
```

finally this kind of href link is generating

```
/public/admin/product/all#3
```

I'm getting only first link value only. What's the wrong with this :(

**Highlight: I'm generating my view with a foreach. I think that is why other links doesn't act as I wish**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, As you are creating anchor element in a loop thus its creating element with same Id.

*Identifiers in HTML must be unique*, use a common class then [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) can be used. like

*Script*

```
 var clearBn = $(".code");
```

*HTML*, Here I have add class `code` to the element and removed Id attribute

```
<a href="#{{$product['product_id']}}" 
  class="btn btn-success btn-lnk code" 
  data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#myModal">+Add File</a>
 </td>
```